# What does this assignment with two back-to-back round brackets do?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to AppsScript/Javascript and trying to learn what [this code passage](https://github.com/brucemcpherson/xmlJsonApi/blob/master/content.gs) does. In it, the author writes

```
var Content = (function (ns) {
  ns.makeContent = function  (e) {
   }  
  return ns;      
}) (Content || {});
```

and is able to call `Content` by

```
function doPost(e) {
  return Content.makeContent (e); 
}
```

What does it mean to have a variable assignment statement that reads `var ... = (...) (...);`?

Comment: [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called immediately invoking function expression. This `(Content || {})` means  the function to be called with `Content` object if that exist or pass an empty object.

Note: This code will give error if the variable is declared with `const` key word

```js
var Content = {
  test: 'Hello'
}

var Content = (function(ns) {
  ns.makeContent = function(e) {}
  return ns;
})(Content || {});

console.log(Content)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! One follow-up please: what does the line `return ns` do? If the function is evaluated anyway and all the function does in this case is to modify an existing object, does it mean that in this case `return ns` is not needed? Or is function return needed as a part of the syntax?

Comment: @Argyll `return ns` will return the `Content ` or if `Content` is undefined then it will return a new object

Answer (score 1):

A function which looks like:

```
(function(){
  ...
})()
```

is what's known as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression. So essentially, it's a function that is run immediately rather than waiting to be called from somewhere else.